# Android OpenGL shader - show image at 1:1 size

Tags: android, opengl-es, scale

Hi I have a 512x512 texture that I would like to display within my GlSurfaceview at a 100% scale at a 1:1 pixel for pixel view.
I have having troubles achieving this and require some assistance. 
Every combination of settings in OnSurfaceChanged and onDrawFrame result in a scaled image. 
Can someone pls direct me to an example where this is possible.

```
private float[] mProjectionMatrix = new float[16];

// where mWidth and mHeight are set to 512
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int mWidth, int mHeight) {
 GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, mWidth, mHeight); 
 float left = -1.0f /(1/ScreenRatio );
 float right = 1.0f /(1/ScreenRatio );
 float bottom = -1.0f ;
 float top = 1.0f   ;
 final float near = 1.0f;
 final float far = 10.0f;
 Matrix.frustumM(mProjectionMatrix, 0, left, right, bottom, top, near, far);
}

@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 glUnused ) {
 ....stuff here 
 Matrix.setIdentityM(mModelMatrix, 0); 
 Matrix.translateM(mModelMatrix, 0, 0, 0, 1);
 Matrix.rotateM(mModelMatrix, 0, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); 
 drawCube(); 
}
```

many thanks,

Comment: The only way you're going to accomplish that is if you use something like `Matrix.frustumM(mProjectionMatrix, 0, 0, mWidth, 0, mHeight, near, far);`

Comment: Thanks Andon, Thats giving me a blank view. Can you explain briefly the relationship between Matrix.TranslateM and Matrix.frustrumM.

Answer (score 1):

There's various options. The simplest IMHO is to not apply any view/projection transformations at all. Then draw a textured quad with a range of (-1.0, 1.0) for both the x- and y-coordinates. That would get your texture to fill the entire view. Since you want it displayed in a 512x512 part of the view, you can set the viewport to cover only that area:

```
glViewport(0, 0, 512, 512);
```

Another possibility is that you reduce the range of your input coordinates to map to a 512x512 area of the screen. Or scale the coordinates in the vertex shader.

You didn't specify what version of OpenGL ES you use. In ES 3.0, you could also use `glBlitFramebuffer()` to copy the texture to your view.

Comment: Thanks Reto, As stated in the question I am already forcing the viewport to 512,512. IM getting confused I think creating all the elements together. GlsurfaceView size is 512 . image is 512 . viewport is 512. I think I'm getting unstuck on the Matricies.

Comment: As I mention in the first paragraph, don't set up any matrices at all. Don't even apply any transformations in your vertex shader.

Comment: Thanks Again Reto. do you mean just delete all the matrices? Ill look into my vertex shader as well.

Comment: Yes, apply no transformations. In the vertex shader, you can simply pass through the position and texture coordinate attributes to the fragment shader. You can even avoid having a separate attribute for texture coordinates because you can easily calculate them from the position. Since your position coordinates will be in the range (-1, 1), and you want texture coordinates in the range (0, 1), you can use something like `texCoord = position * 0.5 + 0.5` in the vertex shader to calculate the texture coordinates.